When using module nRF24L01, function write blocks the code, even though stopListening was called
The below code shows the problem. Function radio.write() blocks the entire code. The "Before stopListening" and "Before write" both get printed, but "After write" doesn't.
(We are using something similar to Arduino.)
#include "nrf24.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>

#define MSG_SIZE 19
static char buffer[MSG_SIZE];

const uint8_t address[] = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89 };
const uint8_t address2[] = { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x90 };

extern "C"
void user_init(void) {

  // Calls radio.begin(), radio.setChannel() 
  setup_nrf();
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, address2);
  radio.startListening();

  while (1) {

    if (radio.available()) {
      radio.read(buffer, 1);
      printf("%d\n", buffer[0]);
    }

    if ((read_byte_pcf() & button1) == 0) {
      printf("Before stopListening\n");
      radio.stopListening();
      printf("Before write\n");

      buffer[0] = 123;
      radio.write(buffer, 1);
      printf("After write\n");

      radio.startListening();

    }

  }

} 

I tried calling radio.openWritingPipe(address); before the write each time, but that didn't help.
